# Redux pre process store before mapStateToProps?

Tags: redux, react-redux

I have a redux store with multiple teams.

```js
    const store = {
       selectedTeamId: 'team1';
       teams: {
          team1: { ... },
          team2: { ... },
          team3: { ... },
       },
    };
```

At any given time a `teamId` is set.

Now given that I must select the team using the ID each time I call `mapStateToProps()`, I feel this is cumbersome.

Instead of doing this all the time:

```js
    mapStateToProps({ selectedTeamId, teams }) {
       return {
           team: teams[selectedTeamId],
       }
    }
```

Can I pre-process the store using some middleware instead of repeating this pattern in map state to props?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a middleware for this scenario isn't performant (if I understood your question correctly :) ). I will outline 3 options you can use to achieve this:

**Option 1**

return both `selectedTeamId` and `teams` in `mapStateToProps`, this will allow you to find the team you need for each selected id:

```
mapStateToProps({ selectedTeamId, teams }) {
    return {
        selectedTeamId,
        teams
    }
}
```

That way you can access these props in `render`:

```
render() {
    const { teams, selectedTeamId } = this.props;
    return <Team team={teams.find(team => team.id === selectedTeamId)} />
}
```

Note: `<Team />` is just a component I made for demonstration

**Option 2**

you can use [reselect](https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect) library to avoid recomputing this prop:

```
import { createSelector } from 'reselect'

const teams = state => state.teams;
const selectedTeamId = state => state.selectedTeamId;

const subtotalSelector = createSelector(
  teams,
  selectedTeamId,
  (teams, selectedTeamId) => items.find(team => team.id === selectedTeamId)
)
```

**Option 3**

Create an action that will dispatch 'SELECT_TEAM' with the `teamId`

```
export function setSelectedTeam(id) {
    return { type: types.SELECT_TEAM, payload: id };
}
```

Create a reducer for that type and return `selectedTeam`:

```
[types.SELECT_TEAM]: (state, payload)=> {
    return {
        ...state,
        selectedTeam: state.teams.find(team => team.id === payload.id)
    };
},
```

That way you can have a selector for `selectedTeam`

```
export const getSelectedTeam = state => state.selectedTeam;
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks, it's the repeating of this pattern that I'm actually trying to void `team={teams.find(team => team.id === selectedTeamId)}`. Coding it once somewhere redux-related, rather than repeating it many times over in component.

Comment: I was thinking I could potentially wrap the redux connect component, with my own pre-processing connect component.

Comment: @denski - have you considered using `reselect`? I've added this option as an alternative approach. Using it will help you memoize these props, and render only if one of them changed

Comment: I've just spent time using reselect and it's ideal for my needs thanks.

Comment: I added in an answer describing how I abstracted away the need for having selectors in `mapStateToProps`.

Answer (score 2):

Approach suggested by Redux docs is to create a selector for currently active team and reuse it across all components

```
// selector itself is a pure function of state
// usually put in separate file, or in file with reducer
const activeTeamSelector = state => state.teams.teams[state.teams.selectedTeamId]


// in connect
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  activeTeam: activeTeamSelector(state),
})
```

That, of course, if you are using [combineReducers](https://redux.js.org/api/combinereducers/) and teams reducer is called `teams` in state. If you aren't, and `selectedTeamId` and `teams` are contained right in your store, following will work

```
const activeTeamSelector = state => state.teams[state.selectedTeamId]
```

Notice how I only had to change selector for this, and not every `mapStateToProps` in all the components

read more about [Normalizing Store State](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/normalizing-state-shape) and [Computing Derived Data](https://redux.js.org/recipes/computing-derived-data) in Redux docs

Answer (score 1):

I eventually used `reselect`, with thanks to the recommendation of @jank.

One of things I wanted to do was abstract away the need for selectors to appear in `mapStateToProps`. In order to do that, I wrapped redux `connect`. This allows insertion of a `denormalizer` function before mapStateToProps.

```js
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { createSelector } from 'reselect';

const getActiveTeamId = state => state.activeTeamId;
const getAllTeams = state => state.teams;

const teamSelector = createSelector(
  getActiveTeamId,
  getAllTeams,
  (activeTeamId, teams) => teams[activeTeamId],
);

function denormalizer(mapStateToProps) {
  return state => {
    return mapStateToProps({ team: teamSelector(state) });
  };
}

export default function reConnect(mapStateToProps = null, actions = null) {
  const denormalizedMapStateToProps = denormalizer(mapStateToProps);

  return function callConnect(Component) {
    return connect(denormalizedMapStateToProps, actions)(Component);
  };
}
```